# editing a text file on my host using php

Tags: php, web, ftp

I have created a website. Suppose I have a webpage **index.php** and a txt file **updateContent.txt**.

How can I manipulate the txt file via the php code on my host? I have tried this code but it doesn't work! And it says

> Unable to open file!

Is there another way?

```
//database connection
$quryForGetLastUpdate="SELECT englishword FROM allowedwords";
         $myfile = fopen("./updateContent.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
                foreach ($dbh->query($quryForGetLastUpdate) as $row){
                    //out the mean in txt file
                    $txt = $row['englishword'];
                    fwrite($myfile, $txt);
                }
fclose($myfile);
```

And its My Host Content...
[image]

Comment: *"but it doesnt work !!!"* - http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php - http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php

Comment: why u r not use database ?instead of text file.

Comment: thanks i have added error report to it now it say
`Warning: fopen(./updateContent.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/vhosts/akdi.6te.net/updateakd.php`

Comment: You're welcome. Well, there you go, it's a permissions issue for folder/file (more than likely). Make sure both can be written to and ownership. Use a proper/full system path also.

Comment: you mean like this
`fopen("http://akdi.6te.net/updateContent.txt", "w")`

Comment: no, a system path is `/var/home/user/you/path/to/folder/` and not a URL.

Comment: use `phpinfo()` and look under environment and you will see what your system path is.

Comment: plz give a description on that directories var,home,user....

Comment: no i have written it that is just a piece of my code

Answer (score 1):

1. Are you have a write permissions on this directory
2. Try to use a full pat e.g. "/var/www/html/updateContent.txt". Path is on server side and may differ from this seen in ftp client.

Comment: i have added error report to it now it say Warning: `fopen(./updateContent.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/vhosts/akdi.6te.net/updateakd.php`

Comment: So you really have a write permissions problem. Try to make folder and give to apache or any other  user that  php use a write permission, then relocate a file in that folder

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing like this, follow this method.

```
//database connection
$quryForGetLastUpdate="SELECT englishword FROM allowedwords";
         $txt="";
         foreach ($dbh->query($quryForGetLastUpdate) as $row){
            //out the mean in txt file
            $txt .= $row['englishword'];
         }
file_put_contents("updateContent.txt",$txt);
```